# Why does the regular expression /[_-%]/ break JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

The following JavaScript outputs nothing (not even "false"), and indeed stops any other JavaScript on the page from running:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/[_-%]/);
document.write(pattern.test("foo"));
```

What is it about this regular expression that does this? If any one of the three characters (_, -, or %) is removed, everything works normally. And if the order of the three characters is changed at all, everything works normally.

Comment: It's interesting to note that if you swap the `%` and `_`, it will work, but probably not as you expect (`%` is ASCII 45 and `_` is ASCII 137).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A hyphen in a [  ] block is used for ranges. So _ to % is invalid.
You can escape it:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/[_\-%]/);
```

or move to the start:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/[-_%]/);
```

or to the end:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/[_%-]/);
```

Since regex knows that a hyphen at the start (or end, thanks BrunoLM!) means a literal hyphen and not a range.

Answer (score 1):

It's because in the interpreter thinks it's dealing with a range. Just like `/[a-z]/` will match any character between `a` and `z`, `/[_-%]/` will (try to) match any character between `_` and `%`. This doesn't make sense, so JavaScript stops. Putting the hyphen as the first or last character will fix the issue.

Comment: Is also possible to avoid the range semantic by escaping the - with \-.

Answer (score 0):

It's the dash in the middle.  JavaScript treats `[_-%]` as a character class range, similar to `[A-Z]`.  I'm guessing the browser you're using simply doesn't handle this case very well.  I suggest moving the hyphen to the front, or escaping it with a backslash (`\-`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following instead:

```
/[-_%]/
```

The - would have been interpreted to be a range. You can also use \-